# undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass..why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, show, categories, movie

i've been working on new app it's like IMDB and i added category model which it works fine with the association but i'm having problem in Displaying movies by category in category controller:

```
def show
  @category = Category.find(params[:id])
  @category_movies = @category.movies
end
```

in the category show page:

```
<h align = "center"><%= "Category: " + @category.name %></h1>
<%= render 'movies/movies', obj:@category_movies %>
```

and in index i did:

```
<div class= "row">
    <% @movies.each do |movie|%>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <%= link_to (image_tag movie.image.url(:medium), class: 'image'), movie %>
        </div>
       </div>
   <% end %>
</div>
```

so i got an error undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
any ideas

Comment: So, where is your index method? Because `each` only found in `index` page based on your post.

Comment: Paste the code for your index action

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your partial, you use `@movies` but in the controller, you are calling it `@category_movies` - you will need to use the same variable name, or use local variables.

eg with local variables:

```
<%= render 'movies/movies', :movies => @category_movies %>

# and in the partial
<% movies.each do |movie|%>
```

Note: not tested for bugs and typos...

Answer (score 0):

Instance variable `@category_movies` must be the same in the controller and in the views :)
`@movies` is not declared so it's nil !